# How to enable or disable a check box based on the condition in the text box in silver light?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a textbox, and a check box next to it.
If user enters the value $240, then check box is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Well it can be achieved easily. Just register the GotFocus event of a TextBox in the constructor as`txtbox.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(txtbox_LostFocus);`
Now in your handler write the following code and you are ready to go

```
void txtbox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Convert.ToInt32(txtbox.Text) == 240)
        {
             checkbox.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
```